# How to include database file and SQL Server Express installer for Deployment with VS2010

Tags: setup-project, sql-server-2008-express

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2008 Express

I would like to deploy my project with setup and deployment project and would like to include the SQL Server database file and SQL Server 2008 Express installer, so the user can easily install and use the application.

Please anyone show me step by step instructions.

Or any link that can help me to solve this out

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use prerequisites check box, this will install sql server on client machine